# What exactly does "tally ho" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions, meaning-in-context, idiom-meaning

I heard this *tally ho* in a youtube video (British). I also heard it in the movies "Jack the Giant Slayer", and "Spiderman 1". I understand it's some kind of expression or exclamation or idiom to say in certain circumstances.

I've googled for this, I just found that it is used to say *a huntsman's cry to the hounds on sighting a fox*, and *a cry of tally ho*. First, I don't get it, and second I can't find a connection between that "tally ho" and the videos I heard it from.

Comment: The etymology is not particularly clear, but you could have learned as much as I have by googling 'tally ho" and "etymology."  It seems to have come from a French word for alerting the dogs, 'taïaut.'

Comment: @MichaelOwenSartin: To add to the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tally-ho) "tally-ho" comes French *taïaut* or *tayaut* evolved from Middle French *ta-ho* formed from two onomatopœic words: *ta* that was the cry to stimulate the animals and *ho* a rallying cry. It was used in foxhunting to signal the beast, and also in classical French to expose someone to public condemnation.

Comment: @Laure I assumed the _ho_ part was for [_over there_](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ho#Interjection).

Comment: @IQAndreas: Old French also had [ho](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ho#Old_French) used to call attention so we can choose whichever we like I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although (as you brought out) it may have bore [a different meaning in the past](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tally-ho#Etymology), nowadays it is (over)used in movies for when people are about to jump off a high structure or cliff, and sometimes even for jumping into the fray or a dangerous situation.

It is used pretty much like other exclamations such as *Geronimo!* or *Away we go!*

**As a side note:** I'm not sure if people actually use the phrase in real life, or if it's just a movie trope, such as the iconic *Let's get out of here!* or *I'm getting a bad feeling about this*.

Comment: I can't imagine either Bruce Willis or Schwarzenegger saying "tally ho!" :) It sounds too posh and too British.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Well, I could imagine Bruce Willis saying *Tally-ho, m----rf----r!*; *tally-ho* is more exotic than *yippee-ki-yay* but not any more ridiculous.

Comment: @choster  I watched the Spiderman clip, and the protagonist is scared stiff before he launches himself in mid air. Peter Parker stutters the words as a form of encouragement. Could very well be that movie fans adopted this "cry" whenever faced with a life or death situation. But for me, "tally ho" will always evoke images of aristocratic huntsmen dressed in red blazers, and white jodhpurs riding across the British countryside while hunting a terrified small red fox.

Comment: @Mari-LouA +1, I can't really think "tally ho" without following it with "old chap".

Answer (score 0):

I think of the phrase's use being spoken to a comrade, usually with nervous bravado. Particularly when fixing to go into a tense or hazardous situation like diving in pursuit of an enemy aircraft; or chasing something that could turn on you quickly with dire results.

Answer (score 0):

In the movie The Great Escape, Allied British forces escaped a Nazi prison camp. Upon their escape, they were on a train and some we're being approached by crewman aboard the train apparently checking their identification. One man issued a warning in a whisper to a few of the British men on board, saying "Tally ho" as a warning to be ready as someone was about to approach them. Hence the analogy of the hounds being warned that there is a fox (potential danger) in the midst.